# How do I delete by ID in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-database

I am quite new Android Development and figured I should start by trying to create a simple ToDo List App using SQLite. I have all of the basic functionality in place: adding, updating, and deleting tasks. However, I am adding, updating, and deleting by the title of the task, rather than by the ID. This creates problems with duplicate tasks (e.g. tasks of the same name are deleted simultaneously). After much internet search, I still cannot find a way to do this. I would appreciate any help offered!

Here's my code:

```
public class TaskDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public TaskDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TaskContract.DB_NAME, null, TaskContract.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE + " ( " +
                TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DATE + " DATE);";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(createTable);
    }
}
```

Activity where tasks are shown

```
public class ShowTaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TaskDbHelper mHelper;
    private ListView mTaskListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task);

        mHelper = new TaskDbHelper(this);
        mTaskListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_todo);

        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(
                TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,  // Name of the table to be queried
                new String[]{  // Which columns are returned
                        TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID,
                        TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE,
                        TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DATE},
                null, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int index =     cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
            taskList.add(cursor.getString(index));
        }

        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    task, // What view to use for the items
                    R.id.task_title, // Where to put the string of data
                    taskList); // Where to get the data
            mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            mAdapter.clear();
            mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        cursor.close();
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }

    // TODO: Change to delete by ID, not name
    public void deleteTask(View view) {
        View parent = (View) view.getParent();
        TextView taskTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
        String task = taskTextView.getText().toString();
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        sqLiteDatabase.delete(
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,  // Where to delete
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " = ?",  // Boolean check
            new String[]{task});  // What to delete
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
        updateUI();
    }
}
```

Task adding Code

```
public void addTask(String task, String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE, task);
    contentValues.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DATE, date);
    sqLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
            null,
            contentValues,
            SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
}
```

Comment: Create `Model` of Task with fields `id` and `name` and then create custom `Adapter` then get the `id` when deleting item and delete it from the database

Comment: @aksacha How do I get the ID when deleting the item using a custom adapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String rowId; //Set your row id here
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
sqLiteDatabase.delete(
                TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,  // Where to delete
                KEY_ID+" = ?",  
                new String[]{rowId});  // What to delete
sqLiteDatabase.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ?",new String[]{Long.toString(id)} );
db.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method to delete By id

```
  public void deleteData(String tableName, Integer id) {

    try {
        if (mWritableDB != null) {
            mWritableDB.execSQL("delete from " + tableName + " Where id = " + id);
        }
    } catch (Exception _exception) {
        _exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is when I create a task I don't store the ID

Comment: Its better your create model(POJO) your task and in that you maintain your ID when you fetch list and better to use recycler view for this purpose

Comment: I'm not sure what model(POJO) means. Can you explain that? And what is better about a recycler view?

Comment: POJO is java class with getter and setter with all params are required by you and recycler view is better because to remove a list from view is easy and can get position of item

Comment: @CL can you explain me please i wanna know

Comment: Do you know why we use catch block

Comment: if there is any error even if in my sql query also it give m error. if you dont have idea about it i can explain by code

Comment: @NikhilSharma Thank you for your help! After your advice, and some online research, I will implement a recycler view. I never knew how much more powerful it was over ListView. I will also make a POJO class for Tasks. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your most welcome my frnd if my suggestion really helps you so hit up button .Thanks!